# Passing value into progress bar (twitter bootstrap, Flask)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm using twitter bootstrap to plot a progress bar, but I'd like to specify the amount of progress.  To do this, I'm using a Python string, thePercent, that is being passed to the html (via Flask).

thePercent:

```
"width: 35%"
```

Currently, my predictions.html file looks like this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;">
    <span class="sr-only">{{thePercent}}% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My view.py file looks like this:

```
@app.route("/result")
def resultpage():

    IDnumber = int(request.args.get('ID'))

    with db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT AnimalID, AdoptionProbability FROM Demo_Data WHERE AnimalID = '" + str(IDnumber) + "' LIMIT 1")
        query_results = cur.fetchall()

    thePercent= str(int(query_results[0][1])) 
    theDog = "static/PetPics/" + str(int(query_results[0][0]))
    print thePercent

    return render_template("predictions.html", thePercent=thePercent, theDog = theDog)
```

Edit: Thanks for the responses so far.  I should mention that thePercent gets successfully passed to the predictions.html file.  For example,

```
        <div class = "caption-full">

                <a>I have a {{thePercent}} % chance of success</a>
        </div>
```

returns the correct output

Edit: I should mention that the following code works:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div id = 'progressBar' class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%;">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script> $("#progressBar").css("width",'90%'); </script>

    <span class="sr-only">{{thePercent}} Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I try to replace '90%' with {{thePercent}}, I get an error.

I think the problem is I've effectively mixed JQuery with Jinja. But how would one go about changing the progress bar just using Jinja?

Comment: By default Flask uses Jinja2 templates.  It doesn't look like you're using a template or anything at all to pass your variable to the html.  The basic example of how you'd use a Jinja2 template is here:  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#basic-api-usage

Answer (score 2):

You aren't printing out the value of `thePercent`, you are setting the `style` attribute equal to the value `'thePercent'`. You need to use Jinja's `{{}}` to output its value, just as you do in your edit.

```
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:{{ thePercent }}%">
```

**Edit:**

I updated the `style` attribute. Because `thePercent` contains just the percentage and not the full value for the attribute, the rest of the value (i.g., `width` and the `%`) needs to be handled in the template.

Comment: Then you need to share more code. What does your view look like? Is this the template file loaded by the view or is it loaded by another template? If the latter, how do you load it?

Comment: I pasted in code from my view.py file.  Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: This solution works fine, but PyCharm underlines it as an error somehow. 
The template does render correctly with the width of the progress bar updating.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I think I figured it out:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div id = 'progressBar' class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%;">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script> $("#progressBar").css("width","{{thePercent}}"); </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in ror, so I'd presume its similar.  One way you can do it is using jQuery.  Just pass in your percent var to something like:

```
$("#progressBar").css("width",<%=thePercent%>);
```

I think the reason its not working the way you add it is because you are not escaping it to be rendered as part of your backend template (so it should be: `{{thePercent}}` ) before client side is rendered.

I would check the source and see if thePercent is actually being printed as the value or just as text.